# Offline download of Enhanced Dictation in Mavericks

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I want to use the amazing [Enhanced Dictation](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#dictation) Feature available in OSX Mavericks, like the screenshot says is required a download of 785 MB.

[image: dictation-screenshot]

The only problem is that in my home where i have my Mac i haven't internet connection so i need a way to download some kind of pkg or dmg to use at home when i have my offline Mac.

Is there any way to do that, links are appreciated if exists.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i figure out how to solve it

I wanted to keep the file so I don't have to re-download every time

here is the way tested on mavericks 10.9.3 and it works

download the file 785 mb

when it finished go to

SYSTEM --> LIBRARY -->SPEECH Recognizers

SpeechRecognitionCoreLanguages this is the folder

hit get info and look at the size simply copy and paste that folder and save it , if you need to install in another computer copy and paste the folder to that location , if you ever reinstall the system you don't need to re-download because you already have it

here is the link for the pkg i haven't try this pkg yet i just got you the link

http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/55/13/031-1940/chpuvr2ntbhisy2em872b4j6hsk71croja/SpeechRecognitionCoreLanguage_en_US.pkg

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to do this yet. I hope Apple corrects this soon.

Update: It is now working. Clear the cache of the files on mac of the speech if already present. Then, take McDonald's WiFi or something, and Valaha (spelling).